# Exceptions when calling Kusto API in Android environment

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, azure-data-explorer

I'm working on a Xamarin mobile app which queries some data which is in an ADX cluster. I've setup a project using the Kusto SDK and am testing with the tutorial code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/about-kusto-data):

```
var client = Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider("https://help.kusto.windows.net/Samples;Fed=true");
var reader = client.ExecuteQuery("StormEvents | count");
```

I'm testing against visual studio's android emulator (Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 - API 28) and see that when the first line above is executed the following exception occurs:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.Anchor' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: Function not implemented
  at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents () [0x0008e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher/src/System/IO/FileSystemWatcher.Linux.cs:65 
  at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed () [0x00019] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher/src/System/IO/FileSystemWatcher.cs:664 
  at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents (System.Boolean value) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher/src/System/IO/FileSystemWatcher.cs:163 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(bool)
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.AppSettingsFileProvider.StartWatching () [0x00024] in <108421866c7741bda55f6c9b7c9a34e6>:0 
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.Tweaks.TryRegisterTweaksFile (System.String path, System.String file) [0x000a3] in <108421866c7741bda55f6c9b7c9a34e6>:0 
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.Tweaks.RegisterMandatoryTweaksFiles () [0x00050] in <108421866c7741bda55f6c9b7c9a34e6>:0 
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.Tweaks..ctor () [0x00059] in <108421866c7741bda55f6c9b7c9a34e6>:0 
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.Anchor..cctor () [0x00000] in <108421866c7741bda55f6c9b7c9a34e6>:0
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/controlling-tracing) seems to show that this code is involved in client-side tracing, so I decided to disable it with the code it provides:

```
Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.TraceSourceManager.SetTraceVerbosityForAll(
    Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.TraceVerbosity.Fatal
    );
```

Now the code produces a different error:

```
mono_native_thread_id_get assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.CurrentThread.GetMonoThreadId()
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.CurrentThread.get_NativeThreadId () [0x00033] in <9dd19f80b3864692b4a926469c23a2c0>:0 
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.CreationContext..ctor (System.Boolean deserializing, System.Boolean captureCallStack) [0x0004c] in <9dd19f80b3864692b4a926469c23a2c0>:0 
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.CreationContext..ctor (System.Boolean deserializing) [0x00000] in <9dd19f80b3864692b4a926469c23a2c0>:0 
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.CreationContext..ctor () [0x00000] in <9dd19f80b3864692b4a926469c23a2c0>:0 
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.UtilsKeyNotFoundException.Construct_ExceptionCreationContext (System.Boolean deserializing) [0x0000b] in <9dd19f80b3864692b4a926469c23a2c0>:0 
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.UtilsKeyNotFoundException.Construct (System.Boolean deserializing, System.Nullable`1[T] failureCode, System.String failureSubCode, System.Nullable`1[T] isPermanent) [0x00049] in <9dd19f80b3864692b4a926469c23a2c0>:0 
  at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.UtilsKeyNotFoundException..ctor (System.String keyValue, System.String keyType, System.String collection, System.Nullable`1[T] failureCode, System.String failureSubCode, System.Nullable`1[T] isPermanent) [0x0001b] in <9dd19f80b3864692b4a926469c23a2c0>:0 
  at Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringValidator.IsValid (Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder kcsb, System.String& errorMessage) [0x001fd] in <e31358719a0646d580915bb27daf320c>:0 
  at Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringValidator.ValidateProperties (Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder kcsb) [0x00000] in <e31358719a0646d580915bb27daf320c>:0 
  at Kusto.Data.Net.Client.RestClient2..ctor (Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder kcsb, System.Boolean canForwardTokenToTarget) [0x0002c] in <e31358719a0646d580915bb27daf320c>:0 
  at Kusto.Data.Net.Client.RestClient2..ctor (Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder kcsb) [0x00000] in <e31358719a0646d580915bb27daf320c>:0 
  at Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider (Kusto.Data.KustoConnectionStringBuilder builder) [0x0002e] in <e31358719a0646d580915bb27daf320c>:0 
  at Kusto.Data.Net.Client.KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider (System.String connectionString) [0x00020] in <e31358719a0646d580915bb27daf320c>:0
```

That's probably the most "You've hit kernel bedrock" error I've seen in a while, so I think I need to take a step back here. The UtilsKeyNotFoundException gives me the impression this might be a configuration issue, but I get no results when searching for any class with that name. If you have experience with this issue, any insights you have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this, this is the result of a limited .Net core support on Android. We will work to fix the SDK to avoid using the missing .Net APIs in Android.

As a workaround please try the Java SDK.